# cannot resolve symbol (class declaration)

Tags: c#-3.0

I created a class like this :

```
  namespace Web.Models
    {
        public class TimeLineStep
        {

            public string Code { get; set; }

            public string Title;
            public string Description;
            public string Url;

            public string Status;
            public string Category;    

        }
    }
```

And I use this class in a model like this :

```
namespace Web.Models
{
    public class TimelineList
    {

private List<TimelineStep> _steps; 

public List<TimelineStep> Steps 
{
               get 
               {
                     return  this._steps ?? (this._steps = new List<TimelineStep>());
               }
               set 
               {
                              this._steps = value;
               }
}
```

Both are under same namespace but the class TimeLineStep is underlined with red and it says cannot resolve symbol 'TimeLineStep'

Comment: Its not TimelineStep it is TimeLineStep with a capital L

Comment: oh yes I didn't see it .thank you